# Writing unit test for component which uses mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, unit-testing, autocomplete, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I am new to Angular, I am trying to build a text field with autocomplete using Angular 5.

I found this example in [Angular Material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples):

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kopqvokeddbq?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts

I was wondering how to write a unit test for testing the autocomplete functionality. I am setting a value to the input element and triggering an 'input' event and tried selecting the mat-option elements, but see that none of them got created:

Relevant part of my component html:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field class="input-with-icon">
    <div>
      <i ngClass="jf jf-search jf-lg md-primary icon"></i>
      <input #nameInput matInput class="input-field-with-icon" placeholder="Type name here"
             type="search" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="userFormControl" [value]="inputField">
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name"
              (onSelectionChange)="onNameSelect(option)">
    {{ option.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Spec file:

```
it('should filter users based on input', fakeAsync(() => {
    const hostElement = fixture.nativeElement;

    sendInput('john').then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mat-option').length).toBe(1);

        expect(hostElement.textContent).toContain('John Rambo');
    });
}));
function sendInput(text: string) {
    let inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

    inputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    inputElement.focus();
    inputElement.value = text;
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    return fixture.whenStable();
}
```

Component html:

```
userFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.userFormControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(val => this.filter(val))
        );
}

filter(val: string): User[] {
    if (val.length >= 3) {
        console.log(' in filter');
        return this.users.filter(user =>
            user.name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

Before this, I realised that for making the FormControl object set the value, I have to do a inputElement.focus() first, this is something to do with using mat input of angular material. Is there something I have to do to trigger opening the mat-options pane?

How do I make this test work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954940/adam)'s comment to previous answer led me to the [mat-autocomplete component's own test](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.spec.ts), specially [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.spec.ts#L2026). Where you can see that `focusin` is the event that opens the "options".

But they actually open in an overlay outside your component, so in my test `fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mat-option').length` was `0` but if i query over the element `document.querySelectorAll('mat-option')` I got the expected number of options.

To sumarize:

```js
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')); // Returns DebugElement
    inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusin'));
    inputElement.nativeElement.value = text;
    inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const matOptions = document.querySelectorAll('mat-option');
    expect(matOptions.length).toBe(3,
      'Expect to have less options after input text and filter');
```

**Extra ball:** And if you want to click on an option (I did) you can continue like that:

```js
    const optionToClick = matOptions[0] as HTMLElement;
    optionToClick.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
```

Although I didn't success on clicking and getting the value into the input.  Well, I'm not an expert tester, but probably that behaviour should be cover in the own `mat-autocomplete`'s tests (and actually it is) and rely on it?

Answer (score 9):

You need to add more events. I had more or less the same problem as you and it only worked when I triggered the focusin event.

I am using these events in my code. Not sure if all are needed.

```
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusin'));
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
```

You need to add this to your sendInput function...

Comment: FYI https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete.spec.ts#L108

Answer (score 0):

I am building further upon @David answer here.

Providing component which is being tested has `@Output() selectedTimezone = new EventEmitter<string>();`,
and in component template 
`<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectTimezone($event.option.value)">`,
the unit test to capture that appropriate type of event with correct value was emitted is as follows

```
it('should emit selectedTimezone event on optionSelected', async() => { 
    // Note: 'selectedTimezone' is @Output event type as specified in component's signature
    spyOn(component.selectedTimezone, 'emit'); 

    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusin'));

    /**
     * Note, mat-options in this case set up to have array of ['Africa/Accra (UTC
     * +01:00)', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa (UTC +01:00)', 'Africa/Algiers (UTC +01:00)',
     * 'Africa/Asmara (UTC +01:00)']. I am setting it up in 'beforeEach'
     */
    inputElement.nativeElement.value = 'Africa'; 
    inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    await fixture.whenStable();

    const matOptions = document.querySelectorAll('mat-option');
    expect(matOptions.length).toBe(4);

    const optionToClick = matOptions[0] as HTMLElement;
    optionToClick.click();

    // With this expect statement we verify both, proper type of event and value in it being emitted
    expect(component.selectedTimezone.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Africa/Accra');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David's answer I got everything working until selecting an option part.

To make the option selection work, I had to do this;

```
...
matOptions[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
...
```

And you don't have to cast the type of `matOptions[0]` to `HTMLElement`

*Note** I am on Angular 8.0.1 and solution could be different in the new version*

Answer (score 0):

The above upvoted solution is great. Based on it I found a solution with MatInputHarness:

```
const input = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatInputHarness)
await input[0].setValue('12');
(await input[0].host()).dispatchEvent('change');
fixture.detectChanges();

let matOptions = document.querySelectorAll('mat-option');
expect(matOptions.length).toBe(3,
  'Expect to have less options after input text and filter');

matOptions[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
fixture.detectChanges();
```