# Writing unit test for mat-autocomplete that filters customers

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am writing unit test for angular app, precisely angular6. I have mat-autocomplete in the code, all I want to test is the user filtered based on the input I type in the input box. I was inspired by the post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431894/writing-unit-test-for-component-which-uses-mat-autocomplete).

Here is the code snippet of spec file

```
  it('should filter customer',async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let toggleButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    console.log(toggleButton.nativeElement);

    toggleButton.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusin'));
    toggleButton.nativeElement.value = "xyz";
    toggleButton.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const matOptions = document.querySelectorAll('mat-option');
    expect(matOptions.length).toBe(1); //test fails

  })
```

```
  <mat-form-field >
     <input id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
     <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn" style="width:750px;">
         <mat-option  *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async" [value] ="customer.AccountID + '('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (onSelectionChange)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
         {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})
        </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
**typescript.ts**
    this.filteredOptions = this.customerFilterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );  


  _filter(value:any):any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.customers.filter(function (option) {
      if(option.AccountID.includes(filterValue) || option.AccountName.includes(filterValue)) {
        return option;
       }
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: If I define `customers` array then your test works for me

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing initializing your options

```
  it('should filter customer',async () => {
    // Prepare the data
    const option1 = {AccountID: 1, AccountName: 'AccountName1'};
    const option2 = {AccountID: 2, AccountName: 'xyz'}
    // Prepare the data source
    fixture.component.filteredOptions = of([option1,option2])
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let toggleButton = let toggleButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#inputCustomer'));
    console.log(toggleButton.nativeElement);

    toggleButton.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusin'));
    toggleButton.nativeElement.value = "xyz";
    toggleButton.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.component._filter("xyz");
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const matOptions = document.querySelectorAll('mat-option');
    expect(matOptions.length).toBe(1); //test fails

  })
```

This way your component will have some values to select from when you add the autocomplete values.

Bear in mind that you should use the of operator (let me know if it works as I have not tested it) for the async pipe to work.

Comment: Hi Athanasios Kataras,  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>; I am new to rxjs it shows error here

Comment: expect(matOptions.length).toBe(1); fails because  Expected 2 to be 1.

Comment: this is the data I passed   const option1 = {AccountID: 'abc', AccountName: 'AccountName1'};
    const option2 = {AccountID: 'xyz', AccountName: 'xyz'}

Comment: Ok, now you at least have the data in place but they are not filtered. I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: I have updated my question with more info, I have given typescript filter method

Comment: Is there a chance you have another input in your component?

Comment: I have only one input

Comment: even so, try with let toggleButton = let toggleButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#inputCustomer'));

Comment: somehow the value is not being set to input element so  tried component.customerFilterControl.setValue("xyz"); and toggleButton.nativeElement.value = "xyz"; either case test failed

Comment: Try removing the last fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: Sorry earlier I ran the test without expect still it is the same issue

Comment: I removed these lines from your ans  last
    fixture.detectChanges(); from your ans

Comment: Hi Athanasios Kataras, this might be key, this is the how option is selection, I type something in the input box, this filters values and shows as drop down and I select one of the value from drop down list

Comment: Just for a sanity check, can you modify with a fixture.component._filter("xyz"); as I did in the example. I think that your code for filtering is not firing.

Comment: And after that, try in your test `fixture.component.customerFilterControl.setValue("xyz")` to see if it works.

Comment: It didn't change the result